# How do I add a UIView as a sub view in xcode?

Tags: uiview

How do I add a UIView as a sub view in xcode? I want thew subview to be added to the button itself?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/addSubview::

```
UIView *someView;
// ... set value of someView to the parent you want
UIView *childView;
// ... set value of someView to the parent you want

[someView addSubview:childView];
```

Comment: of course an independent issue is to set desired frame of subview, etc. You can also insert the subview at a desired index to get desired Z-order, but the default is to add as topmost subview.

Comment: I have a UIButton named: Button1;


 


I want to add a square inside the button at the left side of the button, how can I do this please?

Comment: I think you should ask a separate question if you need help creating a new UIView of a desired size and position. It's pretty straightforward though, so you can probably just read about the initWithFrame: method at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/initWithFrame: and try it yourself.